# Protect my MYSQL password

Tags: php, mysql, cordova

I have a doubt that if i specify my MySQL password for connection purpose in a PHP file. Will any user be able to see that password by downloading that PHP from my server??

I am trying to develop an Android app using Phonegap where some data is being retrieved from server using PHP>JSON parsing. In this case will i Loose my MYSQL password?

Comment: Not possible. There's a special case however, if you forget to install PHP onto a machine, then people can view your source directly. In that case, you might want to have the password in another location, but that might be inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save the file as a .phps then it will download the source file.  Otherwise, if you save it as a .php, which you most likely have, it will try to load the page as .html which will only show what the php file has put out.

Comment: Make sure to mark the answer with a checkmark [✔] to indicate that it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you create your site properly and do not allow users to execute code, it's safe. Using functions such as [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) with user input would compromise security - you could run `echo $dbpassword;` through eval, which would print out variable `$dbpassword`.

Another caveat is if you allow users to upload files to your server, and those files are executable. That means users could run their own php scripts on your site, so they could include your database connection file, and then echo the variables.

If you are sceptical, you could place your database connection file outside the public folder, and include it from a file inside the public folder.

Other than that, it's safe.

Comment: I was thinking of a simple `file_get_contents('/var/www/password.txt')`, but having that means the PHP would query the disk every time the script is executed -- which would unnecessarily strain the server. If PHP is working fine, that is, tags within `<?php` or `<?` (short tags enabled), then you shouldn't need to worry any further.